# My pixels won't draw in the places I've put them

Tags: canvas, graphics, jframe, bufferedimage, bufferstrategy

I'm trying to draw individual pixels to the screen using a BufferStrategy but when I run the program all the pixels are displayed werid, it's supposed to make 1 square in the top left, but it makes multiple squares that have black lines in between them instead.

Display Class

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import graphics.Render;

public class Display extends Canvas implements Runnable {

public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
public static final int WIDTH = 800;
public static final String TITLE = "Minefront Pre-Alpha 0.01";

private Thread thread;
private Screen screen;
private BufferedImage img;
private Render render;
private int[] pixels;
public boolean running = false;

public Display()
{
    screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    pixels = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
}

public void start() {
    if (running)
        return;
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();

    System.out.println("Working");
}

public void stop() {
    if (!running)
        return;
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Display game = new Display();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setTitle(TITLE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    game.start();

}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(running)
    {
        tick();
        render();
    }
}

private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null)
    {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    screen.render();

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; i++) {
        pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

private void tick() {

}
}
```

Render Class

```
public class Render {
public final int width;
public final int height;
public final int[] pixels;

public Render(int Height, int Width) {
    this.height = Height;
    this.width = Width;
    pixels = new int[Height * Width];
}

public void draw(Render render, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
    for (int y = 0; y < render.height; y++) {
        int ypix = y + yOffset;
        for (int x = 0; x < render.width; x++) {
            int xpix = x + xOffset;

            pixels[xpix + (ypix * width)] = render.pixels[x + (y * render.width)];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Screen Class

```
import graphics.Render;

public class Screen extends Render {

public int Size = 150;
public int Color = 0;
public int R = 0;
public int G = 0;
public int B = 0;

private Render test;

public Screen(int Height, int Width) {
    super(Height, Width);
    test = new Render(Size, Size);
    for (int i = 0; i < Size * Size; i++) {
        Color = RGBtoInt(R, G, B);
        test.pixels[i] = Color;
        R++;
        if (i % 100 == 0 || i % 100 == 1 || i % 100 == 2 || i % 100 == 99 || i % 100 == 98) {
            test.pixels[i] = 16777215;
        } else if (i % 25 == 0 || i % 25 == 1 || i % 25 == 2 || i % 25 == 24 || i % 25 == 23) {
            test.pixels[i] = 3328255;
        } else if (R > 255) {
            R = 0;
            G++;
            if (G > 255) {
                G = 0;
                B++;
                if (B > 255) {
                    B = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private int RGBtoInt(int R, int G, int B) {
    R = (R << 16) & 0x00FF0000;
    G = (G << 8) & 0x0000FF00;
    B = B & 0x000000FF;

    return 0xFF000000 | R | G | B;
}

public void render() {
    draw(test,0,0);
}

}
```

If you know what's happening let me know, thanks.

Comment: Clear the buffer before you use, you can use `Graphics#fillRect` to fill it with a specific color - You really need to start with a clean canvas, this would mean that rendering to `img` is possibly a bad idea, instead, create a new copy of `img` and render to it

Comment: Why does `Screen` need an instance of `Render ` when it extends from `Render `?  Why does the `Render#draw` require an instance of `Render` when it should be simply updating itself?